# Result of cv.findHomography is somewhat distorted/stretched

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, homography

The source-image (camera-view) with keypoints (green dots) is:

[image]

The target-image (top-view) with corresponding keypoints (green dots) is:

[image]

The transformed and merged picture (top-view) is:

[image]

What bothering me is that the further out (relative to the camera) the players are, the more "stretched" out they become (compare the red-circled player between the source- and the target-image).
At the upper end, some of the players are even missing, which makes me believe that the H-matrix:

$$ H = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
-0.07597200563 & -0.883808889 & 306.0068\
-0.05874844307 & -1.283603761 & 635.3404\
-0.00005440938 & -0.002732269 & 1.0000
\end{array}
\right] $$

is wrong. The python-code that I am using to calculate H is:

```
src_list = [[1627, 481], [1843, 491], [1060, 449], [140, 472], [813, 451], [1122, 499], [307, 574], [1332, 460], [1482, 529], [895, 478], [1916, 499], [1913, 567], [6, 643], [319, 467]]
dst_list = [[608, 187], [606, 232], [603, 12], [387, 1], [518, 2], [520, 166], [373, 208], [616, 88], [520, 251], [519, 87], [607, 258], [522, 314], [347, 251], [420, 3]]
src_pts = np.array(src_list).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.array(dst_list).reshape(-1,1,2)
H, mask = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)
```

Is there a way to calculate the amount of distortion for the body-parts, say shoulder, that is not within the playfield-plane? After all, I can safely assume what the approx distance between the plane and some players shoulders is the average body-height of a human.

Comment: you have two issues here, homography and pose estimation. please separate them into individual questions. your projection looks good, but the camera picture is very low resolution. I see all players but one on the projection. maybe your points near the far left side are marked wrong? the players are out-of-plane objects and necessarily get distorted.

Comment: I removed the pose estimation part. I, unfortunately, cannot change the resolution. I also edited the text to clearly define my question: Is there a way to calculate the distortion amount? After all, I can safely assume what the plane's approx distance and some players shoulders is (average human height). Could I not for instance center the players body-parts around his ankles (which would be within the plane).

Comment: impossible. you can't know if a pixel represents an off-plane point (player's head) or a point on the plane (grass 10 meters away from the player). not from a single picture. you're entering the realm of multiple-view geometry. for the given situation, you can calculate how an arbitrary off-plane point would map vs an on-plane point, for the same coordinates on-plane, using the homography (inverted possibly). those coordinates are in the "top-down map" coordinate frame.

Comment: With respect to your last sentence (I think I did not quite understand what you said): would I choose some off-plane point, say the players head, and map it to (some arbitrary) on-plane point, say the players feet and transform using the homography I use to map points between the two pictures?

Comment: please look into decomposing/factoring the homography matrix https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a look—something I still do not understand. Say I would transform a picture of a round pole (5cm in diameter, orthogonal to the ground it is standing upon) from the camera- to the top-view. The "ground-truth" top-view of the pole would always look like a circle independently on what height the plane is measured. If I project on a plane that's on the ground the pole gets distorted (for the reasons mentioned before). As I know about the angle between the ground and the pole would a projection of those points not make sense?